# handlebars with Php, IOS, Android

Tags: php, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm currently looking for a template engine.
For the moment I've an idea on two HandleBars and Mustache.

Mustache is a basic logic-less with many language implementation.

HandleBars are complied Mustache template. But only in JS.

I work on web app and mobile app.
I use PHP and IOS/Android, I've see Mustache have implementation of each of them.

I know Handlebars is better than mustache on compilation.
But in my case, i should use HandleBars or Mustache?

Or HandleBars With mustache?

I'm really lost on it...

Thank's Reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only reason for using Handlebars is compilation, there are compiling implementations of Mustache:

- [Hogan.js in JavaScript](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/).
- [Mustache.php in PHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php).

If you intend to use the Handlebars extensions to the Mustache syntax, [there is a Handlebars implementation in PHP](https://github.com/XaminProject/handlebars.php) as well, and it seems to be pretty solid, but note that it is *much* slower than Mustache.php. I don't know of a Handlebars implementation in Objective-C though.

I personally went the Hogan.js + Mustache.php route, but then I'm the author of Mustache.php so I'm probably biased :)

Comment: I'm currently on a product web site and i want to use layout to all my mustache file. I read Mustache doesn't have Inheritance function...is that true?

Comment: Correct. The current Mustache spec does not include template inheritance. It will (probably?) be standardized in v2.0 of the spec. It has, however, been implemented in several Mustache libraries, but each one does it a different way. For discussion, see the spec issue: https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/38

Comment: That said, I use Mustache in several production apps with no template inheritance. With a proper MV* architecture, I'm less convinced that it's necessary or even advisable to use template inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to fully reuse templates cross-platform, I'd go with Mustache. There's a Mustache javascript implementation that can compile templates: [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/).

Comment: Mmh ok.So i use Mustache on PHP to generate my render, when i need to accès Mustache TPL on javascript i use Hogan.JS. am i understood?``

Comment: @SimonPaitrault For PHP, there are Mustache libs that manage compilation/recompilation on the fly (as in, when template file changes). For JS in *development* mode, just use your templates directly (compile every time before use), for *production*, create a script (we use a PHP script and [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Download_Rhino) to run JS for compilation) that would pre-compile all needed templates.